# How can I save photos at the S23 Ultra's maximum resolution of 12240x16320?

Tags: flutter, camera, android-camera

I am in the process of creating a camera application that runs on the S23 Ultra using Flutter.
However, when creating the camera using Flutter, there is a resolution limitation of 4K (3840x2160), preventing me from saving photos taken at 200MP.

To use the camera, I am using the Flutter camera library with version 0.10.5+4.
For saving captured photos, I am using the Flutter image_gallery_saver library with version 2.0.3.

I am using code similar to the attached file for camera initialization, capturing, and photo saving.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  // Ensure that plugin services are initialized so that `availableCameras()`
  // can be called before `runApp()`
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Obtain a list of the available cameras on the device.
  final cameras = await availableCameras();

  // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
  final firstCamera = cameras.first;

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: TakePictureScreen(
        // Pass the appropriate camera to the TakePictureScreen widget.
        camera: firstCamera,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

// A screen that allows users to take a picture using a given camera.
class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TakePictureScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.camera,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final CameraDescription camera;

  @override
  TakePictureScreenState createState() => TakePictureScreenState();
}

class TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePictureScreen> {
  late CameraController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // To display the current output from the Camera,
    // create a CameraController.
    _controller = CameraController(
      // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
      widget.camera,
      // Define the resolution to use.
      ResolutionPreset.max,
    );

    // Next, initialize the controller. This returns a Future.
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose of the controller when the widget is disposed.
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Take a picture')),
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: _initializeControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return CameraPreview(_controller);
          } else {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          try {
            await _initializeControllerFuture;
            final image = await _controller.takePicture();

            final Uint8List buffer = await image.readAsBytes();
            await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(buffer, name: image.name, quality: 100);
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

On line 55, I am specifying the resolution with `ResolutionPreset.max`.
I believe the issue is that it is using the ultraHigh resolution (3840x2160), which is the highest resolution in the camera library, instead of the highest resolution of the s23 ultra.